# Showing $(¬P\wedge¬Q)\vee(¬P\wedge Q)\equiv¬P\wedge(¬Q\vee Q)$ by distributive law(s)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I want to show that $$(¬P\wedge¬Q)\vee(¬P\wedge Q)\equiv¬P\wedge(¬Q\vee Q)$$
by one of the two Distributivity Laws: $$P\wedge(Q\vee R)\equiv(P\wedge Q)\vee(P\wedge R)$$
$$P\vee(Q\wedge R)\equiv(P\vee Q)\wedge(P\vee R).$$

I have tried to use both laws, without success. However, I managed to show that the statement holds using truth tables.

I think I may be missing something very obvious and/or simple, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Using truth tables is not enough?

Comment: No, in this case it must be shown using one (or both?) of the Distributivity Laws.

Comment: The "simple" thing you are missing is that the solution to your problem means changing some of the letters in the distributive laws you are given. It is the *first* one you need in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Use the first one. The first one says that $P\land (Q\lor R)\equiv (P\land Q)\lor (P\land R)$. In the context of what you are trying to show, switch $P$ to $\neg P$, $Q$ to $\neg Q$, and $R$ to $Q$. Doing so gives the following:
$$
\underbrace{P\land (Q\lor R)\equiv (P\land Q)\lor (P\land R)}_{\text{first distributive law before switch}}\overset{\text{switch}}{\equiv}\underbrace{(\neg P\land\neg Q)\lor(\neg P\land Q)\equiv\neg P\land(\neg Q\lor Q)}_{\text{first distributive law after switch}}.
$$

Comment: +1 However, I prefer the terminology "substitute $\;X\;$ for $\;P\;$" over your "switch $\;P\;$ to $\;X\;$".

Comment: @MarnixKlooster That's fair. The unfortunate problem is clearly the same use of symbols meaning different things. I thought about using colors to denote the swapping, switching, substituting, etc., but that didn't seem entirely necessary.

Comment: Yes. The essential thing here is that a law like this really means, "For any logical expression that one consistently substitutes for $\;P,Q,R\;$,  $\;P\land (Q\lor R)\equiv (P\land Q)\lor (P\land R)\;$ holds."  For the OP, that implicit $\;\forall\;$ and the corresponding substitution/specialization seems to be the thing that is problematic; or perhaps the fact that the law needs to be applied in the right-to-left direction, in this case.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster One bizarre thing is that the OP was active while I posted my answer; thus, maybe s/he doesn't understand my answer, but I find it odd not to leave a comment if something isn't clear (I tried to enhance clarity with the underbraces). Personally, I think the propositional calculus distributions are easiest to see in terms of how multiplication distributions over addition in $\mathbb{R}$. It suddenly makes a lot of sense. Truth tables are okay, but they don't add to understanding at all I don't think.

Comment: The answer is perfectly clear.

Comment: @CKKOY Good! I just wondered because you did not comment and you did not accept. Thus, I thought something was off, but I'm glad to see nothing is. Cheers.